# CAN bus incorrect frame dsPIC33FJ128MC510

Tags: microcontroller, pic, can

I am currently trying to implement a CAN communication between a PC and a microcontroller dsPIC33FJ128MC510 (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/70287C.pdf)

This microcontroller has an integrated CAN controller, and I use an external CAN transceiver to generate the required signal level on the differential pair.

I am facing issue programming the dsPIC33FJ. I used another dsPIC33EV before with the same hardware configuration (transceiver ...) so there is a huge probability the problem comes from the software.

The CAN library does not work for both RX and TX.

I can see a waveform on the scope for both CAN_TX and CAN_RX as well as on the CAN bus itself, and this waveform has the right level and baudrate (1Mbaud). I can see the correct ID and data I sent, as well as DLC, CRC and bit stuffing are considered valid by the scope (see image).

**However it looks like dsPIC33 doesn't emit an ACK when it receives a frame, and the PC doesn't send an ACK when dsPIC33 sends a frame. As a result, neither the PC nor the microcontroller is able to get the message, and the microcontroller is trying to send the message again and again.**

**Image below: CANL waveform when trying to send 0x98, 0x08, 0x98, 0x08, 0x98, 0x08 on CAN adress 0x00240180 to the PC:**

[image]

It is worth mentionning that I used the CAN library generated by MCC. However, this library was originally created for another dsPIC33 (sadly no MCC support for dsPIC33FJ128MC510) which has a different clock configuration for the CAN (no bit CANCKS on C1CTRL1 register for dsPIC33FJ128MC510).

Here is the code for the clock configuration:

```
void CLOCK_Initialize(void)
{
    
    // Fosc = 32.2437MHz
    // Fcy = Fosc/2 = 16.12185MHz
    
    PLLFBD=0x46;                    /* M=70 */
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=1;       /* N1=4 */
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=2;        /* N2=4 */
    OSCTUN=0;                   /* Tune FRC oscillator, if FRC is used */

    
    // AD1MD enabled; PWMMD enabled; T3MD enabled; T4MD enabled; T1MD enabled; U2MD enabled; T2MD enabled; U1MD enabled; SPI2MD enabled; SPI1MD enabled; C1MD enabled; T5MD enabled; I2C1MD enabled; 
    PMD1 = 0x00;
    // IC4MD enabled; IC3MD enabled; OC1MD enabled; IC2MD enabled; OC2MD enabled; IC1MD enabled; OC3MD enabled; OC4MD enabled; 
    PMD2 = 0x00;
    // CMPMD enabled; 
    PMD3 = 0x00;
   
    // CF no clock failure; NOSC FRCPLL; CLKLOCK unlocked; OSWEN Switch is Complete; 
    __builtin_write_OSCCONH((uint8_t) (0x01));
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL((uint8_t) (0x01));
    // Wait for Clock switch to occur
    while (OSCCONbits.OSWEN != 0);
    while (OSCCONbits.LOCK != 1);
}
```

Here is the code for the CAN_Initialization() function:

```
void canConfigureFilterFull(void) {

    //configuré pour n'accepter que les IDS 0x10080 ( correspond à la carte 1 et l'electrolyseur 80)
#define filtre 0x10080

    // Disable interrupts before the Initialization
    IEC2bits.C1IE = 0;
    C1INTE = 0;

    // set the CAN1_initialize module to the options selected in the User Interface

    /* put the module in configuration mode */
    C1CTRL1bits.REQOP = CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE;
    while (C1CTRL1bits.OPMODE != CAN_CONFIGURATION_MODE);

    /* Set up the baud rate*/
    // Tq = 125ns
    //  BAUDRATE 1.00761 Mbaud
    // 0.7617% error rate
    
    C1CFG1 = 0x00; //BRP TQ = (2 x 1)/FCAN; SJW 1 x TQ; 
    C1CFG2 = 0x198; //WAKFIL disabled; SEG2PHTS Freely programmable; SEG2PH 2 x TQ; SEG1PH 4 x TQ; PRSEG 1 x TQ; SAM Once at the sample point; 
    C1FCTRL = 0xC001; //FSA Transmit/Receive Buffer TRB1; DMABS 32; 
    C1FEN1 = 0x01; //FLTEN8 disabled; FLTEN7 disabled; FLTEN9 disabled; FLTEN0 enabled; FLTEN2 disabled; FLTEN10 disabled; FLTEN1 disabled; FLTEN11 disabled; FLTEN4 disabled; FLTEN3 disabled; FLTEN6 disabled; FLTEN5 disabled; FLTEN12 disabled; FLTEN13 disabled; FLTEN14 disabled; FLTEN15 disabled; 
    C1CTRL1 = 0x0000; //CSIDL disabled; ABAT disabled; REQOP Sets Normal Operation Mode; WIN Uses buffer window; CANCAP disabled; 

    /* Filter configuration */
    /* enable window to access the filter configuration registers */
    /* use filter window*/
    C1CTRL1bits.WIN = 1;

    /* select acceptance masks for filters */
    C1FMSKSEL1bits.F0MSK = 0x0; //Select Mask 0 for Filter 0

    /* Configure the masks */
    C1RXM0SIDbits.SID = 0x7ff & (0xF00FF >> 18);
    C1RXM1SIDbits.SID = 0x0;
    C1RXM2SIDbits.SID = 0x0;

    C1RXM0SIDbits.EID = 0b11 & (0xF00FF >> 16);
    C1RXM1SIDbits.EID = 0x0;
    C1RXM2SIDbits.EID = 0x0;

    C1RXM0EID = 0xFFFF & (0xF00FF); //
    C1RXM1EID = 0x00;
    C1RXM2EID = 0x00;

    C1RXM0SIDbits.MIDE = 0x0;
    C1RXM1SIDbits.MIDE = 0x0;
    C1RXM2SIDbits.MIDE = 0x0;

    /* Configure the filters */
    C1RXF0SIDbits.SID = 0x7ff & (filtre >> 18);

    C1RXF0SIDbits.EID = 0b11 & (filtre >> 16);

    C1RXF0EID = 0xFFFF & (filtre);

    C1RXF0SIDbits.EXIDE = 0x0;

    /* FIFO Mode */
    C1BUFPNT1bits.F0BP = 0xf; //Filter 0 uses FIFO

    /* clear window bit to access CAN1 control registers */
    C1CTRL1bits.WIN = 0;

    /*configure CAN1 Transmit/Receive buffer settings*/
    C1TR01CONbits.TXEN0 = 0x1; // Buffer 0 is a Transmit Buffer 
    C1TR01CONbits.TXEN1 = 0x0; // Buffer 1 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR23CONbits.TXEN2 = 0x0; // Buffer 2 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR23CONbits.TXEN3 = 0x0; // Buffer 3 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR45CONbits.TXEN4 = 0x0; // Buffer 4 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR45CONbits.TXEN5 = 0x0; // Buffer 5 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR67CONbits.TXEN6 = 0x0; // Buffer 6 is a Receive Buffer 
    C1TR67CONbits.TXEN7 = 0x0; // Buffer 7 is a Receive Buffer 

    C1TR01CONbits.TX0PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 0 Priority Level
    C1TR01CONbits.TX1PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 1 Priority Level
    C1TR23CONbits.TX2PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 2 Priority Level
    C1TR23CONbits.TX3PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 3 Priority Level
    C1TR45CONbits.TX4PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 4 Priority Level
    C1TR45CONbits.TX5PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 5 Priority Level
    C1TR67CONbits.TX6PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 6 Priority Level
    C1TR67CONbits.TX7PRI = 0x0; // Message Buffer 7 Priority Level

    /* clear the buffer and overflow flags */
    C1RXFUL1 = 0x0000;
    C1RXFUL2 = 0x0000;
    C1RXOVF1 = 0x0000;
    C1RXOVF2 = 0x0000;

    /* configure the device to interrupt on the receive buffer full flag */
    /* clear the buffer full flags */
    C1INTFbits.RBIF = 0;

    /* put the module in normal mode */
    C1CTRL1bits.REQOP = CAN_NORMAL_OPERATION_MODE;
    while (C1CTRL1bits.OPMODE != CAN_NORMAL_OPERATION_MODE);

    /* Initialize Interrupt Handler*/
    CAN1_SetBusWakeUpActivityInterruptHandler(&CAN1_DefaultBusWakeUpActivityHandler);

    /* Enable CAN1 Interrupt */
    IEC2bits.C1IE = 1;
}
```

And here is the code for the DMA initialization:

```
void DMA_Initialize(void) 
{ 
    // Initialize channels which are enabled    

    // AMODE Peripheral Indirect Addressing mode; CHEN disabled; DIR Reads from peripheral address, writes to RAM address; HALF Initiates interrupt when all of the data has been moved; SIZE 16 bit; NULLW disabled; MODE Continuous, Ping-Pong modes are disabled; 
    DMA0CON= 0x20 & 0x7FFF; //Enable DMA Channel later;
    // FORCE disabled; IRQSEL CAN1 RX; 
    DMA0REQ= 0x22;
    // STA 4096; 
    DMA0STA= 0x1000;
    // STB 0; 
    DMA0STB= 0x0000;
    // PAD 0; 
    DMA0PAD= 0x00;
    // CNT 7; 
    DMA0CNT= 0x07;
    // Clearing Channel 0 Interrupt Flag;
    IFS0bits.DMA0IF = false;
    // Enabling Channel 0 Interrupt
    IEC0bits.DMA0IE = 1;

    // AMODE Peripheral Indirect Addressing mode; CHEN disabled; SIZE 16 bit; DIR Reads from RAM address, writes to peripheral address; NULLW disabled; HALF Initiates interrupt when all of the data has been moved; MODE Continuous, Ping-Pong modes are disabled; 
    DMA1CON= 0x2020 & 0x7FFF; //Enable DMA Channel later;
    // FORCE disabled; IRQSEL CAN1 TX; 
    DMA1REQ= 0x46;
    // STA 0; 
    DMA1STA= 0x1000;
    // STB 0; 
    DMA1STB= 0x0000;
    // PAD 0; 
    DMA1PAD= 0x00;
    // CNT 7; 
    DMA1CNT= 0x07;
    // Clearing Channel 1 Interrupt Flag;
    IFS0bits.DMA1IF = false;
    // Enabling Channel 1 Interrupt
    //IEC0bits.DMA1IE = 1; // TODO : delete if CAN does not work

    // AMODE Register Indirect with Post-Increment mode; CHEN disabled; SIZE 16 bit; DIR Reads from peripheral address, writes to RAM address; NULLW disabled; HALF Initiates interrupt when all of the data has been moved; MODE Continuous, Ping-Pong modes are disabled; 
    DMA2CON= 0x00 & 0x7FFF; //Enable DMA Channel later;
    // IRQSEL INT0; FORCE disabled; 
    DMA2REQ= 0x00;
    // STA 4096; 
    DMA2STA= 0x1000;
    // STB 0; 
    DMA2STB= 0x0000;
    // PAD 0; 
    DMA2PAD= 0x00;
    // CNT 0; 
    DMA2CNT= 0x00;
    // Clearing Channel 2 Interrupt Flag;
    IFS1bits.DMA2IF = false;
    // Enabling Channel 2 Interrupt
    //IEC1bits.DMA2IE = 1;
    // MODE Continuous, Ping-Pong modes are disabled; AMODE Register Indirect with Post-Increment mode; CHEN disabled; HALF Initiates interrupt when all of the data has been moved; SIZE 16 bit; DIR Reads from peripheral address, writes to RAM address; NULLW disabled; 
    DMA3CON= 0x00 & 0x7FFF; //Enable DMA Channel later;
    // IRQSEL INT0; FORCE disabled; 
    DMA3REQ= 0x00;
    // STA 4096; 
    DMA3STA= 0x1000;
    // STB 0; 
    DMA3STB= 0x0000;
    // PAD 0; 
    DMA3PAD= 0x00;
    // CNT 0; 
    DMA3CNT= 0x00;
    // Clearing Channel 3 Interrupt Flag;
    IFS2bits.DMA3IF = false;
    // Enabling Channel 3 Interrupt
    //IEC2bits.DMA3IE = 1;

}

void CAN1_TransmitEnable()
{
    /* setup channel 0 for peripheral indirect addressing mode 
    normal operation, word operation and select as Tx to peripheral */

    /* DMA_PeripheralIrqNumberSet and DMA_TransferCountSet would be done in the 
    DMA */
    
    /* setup the address of the peripheral CAN1 (C1TXD) */ 
    DMA_PeripheralAddressSet(CAN1_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, (uint16_t) &C1TXD);

    /* DPSRAM start address offset value */ 
    DMA_StartAddressASet(CAN1_TX_DMA_CHANNEL, (uint16_t) (&can1msgBuf));

    /* enable the channel */
    DMA_ChannelEnable(CAN1_TX_DMA_CHANNEL);
}

void CAN1_ReceiveEnable()
{
    /* setup DMA channel for peripheral indirect addressing mode 
    normal operation, word operation and select as Rx to peripheral */

    /* setup the address of the peripheral CAN1 (C1RXD) */     
    /* DMA_TransferCountSet and DMA_PeripheralIrqNumberSet would be set in 
    the DMA_Initialize function */

    DMA_PeripheralAddressSet(CAN1_RX_DMA_CHANNEL, (uint16_t) &C1RXD);

    /* DPSRAM start address offset value */ 
    DMA_StartAddressASet(CAN1_RX_DMA_CHANNEL, (uint16_t) (&can1msgBuf) );    

    /* enable the channel */
    DMA_ChannelEnable(CAN1_RX_DMA_CHANNEL);
}
```

All the higher level code was tested using another dsPIC33 microcontroller so I don't believe the problem comes from this side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "on CAN adress 0x240180" But your scope pic shows an 11 bit identifier with id 0x272?

Comment: @Lundin, Yes this is part of my problem. It seems I have the correct baud rate and I can see the CAN bus toggling but this does not correspond to the data or the adress I send

Comment: I don't see the code where you actually send though. Also generally when dealing with a new peripheral don't do so in the most complex way you can ever imagine, but rather in the simplest way. Don't use things like CAN filters or DMA until you got the basic functionality working.

Comment: @Lundin, I disabled CAN filters but DMA seems mandatory on dsPIC33 to write CAN ID and data on the CAN registers.